# (Swift) Table View Controller. cellForRowAt is not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Problem:**
tableView Controller is not showing categoryArray items in table.

**Diagnose:**

 - 1st tableView numberOfSections method is triggered and returns 1 (print(categoryArray.count)

 - 2nd tableView cellForRowAt method never starts (print statement does not work)

 - Table View Controller does not need delegate. However, I tried to add tableView.delegate = self

 - x-code restart did not help

**Question:**
Why the 2nd tableView method does not work and how to fix this?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CategoryViewController: UITableViewController {

    var categoryArray = [Category]()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadCategories()
    }

    // MARK: - TableView DataSource Methods

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categoryArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("this should print")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

        let category = categoryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryNameTextField.text = category.name

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of `numberOfSections` implement `numberOfRows`

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return categoryArray.count
   }
   ```
2. At the end of `viewDidLoad` reload the table view

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       loadCategories()
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

   If `loadCategories()` contains something asynchronous reload the table view when the data are loaded.